# Large Session vs multiple queries? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Should I have a large session variable or query the database multiple times? If a user comes to the site, it is almost sure that the user will access the object at least two times, if not more. As such, Should I put this object in a session variable or make multiple queries to the database?
The data gets updated once everyday.

Or is there a better solution altogether?

Comment: Consider database caching, a large session will slow your site down considerably, especially for mobile users.

Comment: How large is the object? Does it differ for each user? How often is it queried?

Comment: There is an implicit perf assumption here, that talking to the database is prohibitively expensive. HTML render time & network transit time typically dwarfs the time spent get data from the DB. If you cache, use the Cache object or the newer MemoryCache object. Session isn't a very good cache, it doesn't have many features targeting caching scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use session variables just to store a couple of particular parameters from the user, not to store DB data. The DB Cache approach seems to be the best option, but make sure it works fine when many users are trying to hit it.